# How can I use systemd to kill a program when another program is not running

Tags: linux, systemd, kill

I'd like that when the program spotify-tui is closed, the service kill spotifyd. How would you write a service like that?

Comment: How is `spotifyd` started now? Does it have a unit file? Can you post its contents?

Comment: Right now it just starts on startup, from ~/.local/autorun

Comment: To be honest, it doesn't sound to me that systemd is relevant / should be involved / considered at all. Some shell wrapper (that starts both spotifyd and spotify-tui) that makes use of shell trap to kill spotifyd upon exiting seems way more sensical for your case.

Comment: If you are not using systemd, it's safe to ignore the service and just run the script in background. But this question is about systemd.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially something like the following:

```bash
while true; do
  if ! pgrep spotify-tui; then
    pkill spotifyd
    exit
  fi
  sleep 10
done
```

then put into any background service you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watchdog to verify if the program freezes.
Take a look in

[systemd for Administrators, Part XV](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/watchdog.html)

Comment: Adding some relevant details from the link could be useful, especially if the link dies... Please [edit] and update your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created the service:

**~/.local/share/systemd/spotifyd-autokill.service** - calls the daemon

```bsh
[Unit]
Description=spotifyd auto-killer (when spotify-tui is not running)

[Service]
# Full path here is required
ExecStart="/home/zeioth/.local/share/systemd/user/daemons/spotifyd-autokill.sh"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**~/.local/share/systemd/user/daemons/spotifyd-autokill.sh** - does the actual work

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while true; do

  if `ps -ef | grep "alacritty --title spotify-tui" | awk {'print $2" "$8'} | grep -v grep > /dev/null`; then
    echo "Spotify-tui is running: No action taken."
  else
    echo "Spotify-tui is not running: Closing spotifyd."
    killall -9 "spotifyd" 2> /dev/null
  fi
  sleep 120

done
```

**~/.local/bin/spotify-tui** - launches spotifyd when you open spotify-tui

```bsh
spotifyd
alacritty --title 'spotify-tui' --config-file ~/.config/alacritty/monokai.yml -e zsh -c 'source ~/.zshrc && cd ~/workspaces/git-forks/spotify-tui && cargo run' &
```